# Goldstein Mechanics, Ch.1 Derivation 3

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram

In the Derivations sections of the First chapter of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics, we find the following question:

> Suppose a system of two particles is known to obey the equations of motion, Eqs.  (1.22) and (1.26). From the equations of the motion of the individual particles show  that the internal forces between particles satisfy both the weak and the strong laws  of action and reaction. The argument may be generalized to a system with arbitrary  number of particles, thus proving the converse of the arguments leading to Eqs. (1.22)  and (1.26).

The equations (1.22) and (1.26) are:

$$\begin{align}
M\ddot{R} &= F_{\text{total}}^{(e)} \tag{1.22} \\
\dot{L}_{\text{total}} &= N_{\text{total}}^{(e)} \tag{1.26}
\end{align}$$

where $\ddot{R}$ is the acceleration of the center of mass of the system, $(e)$ stands for "external", $L$ is the angular momentum and,
\begin{align}
N_{\text{total}}^{(e)} = \sum_{i} (\mathbf{r}_i \times \mathbf{F}^{(e)}_i)
\end{align}

Here, the ***weak law of action-reaction*** is that the action-reaction (internal) forces among particles are equal and opposite while the ***strong law of action-reaction*** is that they are central (along the line joining the particles) along with being equal and opposite.

While it is straightforward to prove this for two particles, the generalization part is not at all obvious.

How do we show this for the general case of $n$ particles?

Answer (score 0):

For a general system with $N$ particles, the equation of motion for particle $i$ is given by
$$
m_i \ddot{\mathbf{r}}_i = \mathbf{F}_i + \sum_{k\neq i} \mathbf{f}_{k\to i},
$$
where $\mathbf{F}_i$ is the external force on particle $i$ and $\mathbf{f}_{k\to i}$ is the force from particle $k$ to $i$.

On the one hand, if Equation 1.22 is a universal law, it can be applied to a subsystem composed of any two particles, e.g. particle $i$ and $j$. So we have
$$
M_{ij} \ddot{\mathbf{R}}_{ij} = \mathbf{F}_i + \mathbf{F}_i + \sum_{k\neq i,j} (\mathbf{f}_{k\to i} + \mathbf{f}_{k \to j}).
$$
Here $M_{ij} = m_i + m_j$ is the total mass of particle $i$ and $j$, and $\mathbf{R} = (m_i \mathbf{r}_i + m_j \mathbf{r}_j)/M_{ij}$ is the displacement of their mass center.

On the other hand, we have
$$
m_i \ddot{\mathbf{r}}_i = \mathbf{F}_i + \sum_{k\neq i} \mathbf{f}_{k\to i}, \quad
m_j \ddot{\mathbf{r}}_j = \mathbf{F}_j + \sum_{k\neq j} \mathbf{f}_{k\to j},
$$
leading to
$$
M_{ij} \ddot{\mathbf{R}}_{ij} = \mathbf{F}_i + \mathbf{F}_i + \sum_{k\neq i,j} (\mathbf{f}_{k\to i} + \mathbf{f}_{k \to j}) + \mathbf{f}_{i\to j} + \mathbf{f}_{j \to i}.
$$

Now we can conclude that $\mathbf{f}_{i\to j} + \mathbf{f}_{j \to i} = 0$， and it must hold for any two particles in the system.

The derivation of the strong law of action-reaction from equation (1.26) for a system with an arbitrary number of particles is similar.

Comment: Equation 1.22 has not yet been proved to be a universal law. The question statement merely states that GIVEN 1.22 ( and 1.26) is obeyed, weak law (and strong law) is also obeyed. And this must be proved for N particles.

Comment: @VinceWizd If equation 1.22 only holds for a single system. then Newton's law can not be derived.